# PHP mail() returns ‘sh: -t: command not found’

Tags: php

I've tried to run the code online on Site **http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php**
But i keep getting an error PHP mail() returns ‘sh: -t: command not found’.
I really want a good Soln here. 
Here is my code:-

```
    <?php
    $to='vbahulkar@gmail.com';
    $subject='Birthday Reminders';
    $message='
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>B'day</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
   ';
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'. "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder<bbahulkar@gmail.com>'."\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    ?>
```

Comment: problem in this `B'day`

Comment: Probably fix the syntax error first? It should be `B\'day`

Comment: i just corrected it but still not getting output ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix `B'd` to `B\'d`

and

You forgot to include one header. Edit `=` to `.=`

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'. "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the solution to the OP entailed escaping a single quote, this error message for me meant something else.

I'm using a Docker container, and the base image did not have sendmail installed. This means that when PHP inferred that the sendmail command would be " -t -i", the result would be " -t -i", which would explain the error message above.

In my case, the solution was to install sendmail. In my Debian-based image, I ran:

```
apt-get install -y sendmail
```

`sudo` might be needed, depending on what user you run `apt-get` as.

You'll want to test sendmail via PHP to make sure it works as intended. I found [this link](https://www.conetix.com.au/support/article/simple-php-mail-test) to have what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Open php.ini file and check for the line of sendmail_path

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

However, the issue will auto-resolve if you upgrade your PHP to latest stable 5 or 7